# Redux reducer design for large state within a single module

Tags: redux, reduce

I have come across two kinds of reducer design for handling a large state within a single module.
The first approach is to have all the variables inside a single large state and have one reducer function.

```
const initialState = {
   results: [],
   pagination: {},
   filters: [],
   appliedFilters = [],
}

const reducer = (st = { ...initialState }, action) => {
  const state = st;
  switch (action.type) {
     case 'SEARCH':{
         return {
           ...state,
           results: action.results,
           pagination: action.pagination,
           filters: action.filters,
           appliedFilters: action.appliedFilters 
     },
     case 'APPLY_FILTER':{
         return {
           ...state,
           results: action.results,
           pagination: action.pagination,
           filters: action.filters,
           appliedFilters: action.appliedFilters 
     },
     case 'PAGINATE':{
         return {
           ...state,
           results: action.results,
           pagination: action.pagination,           
     }          
}
```

The second approach is to have multiple reducers for the sub items in the data.

```
export function applications(state = [], { type, results}) {
  switch (type) {
    case SEARCH:
      return results;   
   case INIT_RESULTS:
      return [];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export function pagination(state = null, { type, paginationData }) {
  switch (type) {
    case SEARCH:
      return paginationData;   
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export function filters(state = [], { type, filterData }) {
  switch (type) {
    case SEARCH:
      return filterData;
    case UPDATE_FILTERS:
      return filterData;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I think both have their own pros and cons. Considering scalability and modularization which one is a better pick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, both of these are very far off our official recommendations.

- you should have a "slice" reducer for each sub-state (that rules out your first option
- you should not treat reducers as "setting a value", but move the whole "calculating how to get the value" into the reducer and handle your action as just "describing an event that happened"
- you should be using the official Redux Toolkit which we are recommending & teaching as the default way of writing Redux sinde 2019. Seriously, look at it. It is about 1/4 of the code. No more switch..case reducers or ACTION_TYPES.

Please give the [Redux Style Guide](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/) a read and to learn modern Redux with Redux Toolkit, please follow the [official Redux Tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts)